# How to use Java libraries in Python

Tags: java, python, jython

I have a Java library in a jar and I want to use the methods from a Python interpreter. I know that I can use Jython for this, but I do not want to use Jython due to performance reasons. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: How do you imagine this would work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is something called [jpype](http://jpype.sourceforge.net/), but I'm not sure that's a better fit than jython. In general, jython isn't really slower than python, is it?

[This](http://strattonbrazil.blogspot.se/2011/08/performance-gains-in-jython-252.html) guy at least seems to think jython has gotten pretty fast in 2.5.2 and 2.5.3 is "final" now so that might improve things further.